# Scroll Top Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I made the scroll to top and scroll to bottom in `jquery`. In that i make to scroll as with percentage. For example:
If the scroll from top to bottom is **`50%`** then it scroll from top to bottom as **`50%`** it already works. But now i want to scroll the 50% if i again click then it scroll the remaining 50% to the bottom of the page. I am not sure how to do this in jquery.

Here is the fiddle  Any suggestion would be great.
http://jsfiddle.net/TkYpY/

Thanks,
vicky

Comment: Your question is not clear - what are you trying to achieve? It seems odd to scroll 50% of the total distance at a time, as you will never reach either the top or the bottom.

Comment: In your jsfiddle even the top and bottom doesn't work.  Have you considered checking out [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)?  It's pretty handy and may help you out a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#spnTop').on("click", function () {
var percentageToScroll = 50;
var percentage = percentageToScroll / 100;
var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
if(scrollAmount > 0 )
{
scrollAmount = scrollAmount - (height * percentage);
}

console.log('scrollAmount: ' + scrollAmount);
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollAmount
}, 'slow', function () {
    console.log("reached top");
});

});

var scrollAmount = 0;
$('#spnbottom').on("click", function () {
var percentageToScroll = 50;
var percentage = percentageToScroll / 100;
var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

 if(   scrollAmount < height)
 {
scrollAmount = scrollAmount + height * percentage;
 }
console.log('scrollAmount: ' + scrollAmount);
jQuery("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: scrollAmount
}, 900);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not scroll on the second click as you have already reached the scrollAmount.

If you want to scroll further then declare var scrollAmount outside the function and when you click again on the bottom link, calculate the next scroll Amount with max being your document height and add it to the global scrollAmount declared var.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#spnTop').on("click", function () {
var percentageToScroll = 80;
var percentage = percentageToScroll / 100;
var height = $(document).scrollTop();
var scrollAmount = height * (1 - percentage);

console.log('scrollAmount: ' + scrollAmount);
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollAmount
}, 'slow', function () {
    console.log("reached top");
});
```

});

```
var scrollAmount = 0;
$('#spnbottom').on("click", function () {
var percentageToScroll = 50;
var percentage = percentageToScroll / 100;
var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
scrollAmount = scrollAmount + height * percentage;
console.log('scrollAmount: ' + scrollAmount);
jQuery("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: scrollAmount
}, 900);
});
```

Comment: I have just modified two lines in your jsfiddle. var scrollAmount = 0; and scrollAmount = scrollAmount + height * percentage;

Comment: Thanks @Girish Sakhare it works. can you tell me to do the same thing for bottom to top?

Comment: Hi @Vicky do the same thing only - the scrollAmount if its > 0. scrollAmount = scrollAmount  - (height * (1 - percentage));

Comment: Thanks @Girish Sakhare I tried this is the fiddle can you explain me what shall i need to change http://jsfiddle.net/TkYpY/77/

Answer (score 1):

I modified your fiddle a bit. Seems to me some calculation problem. [Here is your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkYpY/1/) .
Is this what you needed?

First declare a global variable `height` with default value.

In top scroll code, replace
`var height = $(document).scrollTop();` 
with 
`height -= $(document).height() - $(window).height();`

and in bottom scroll replace this `var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();` with `height += $(document).height() - $(window).height();` .

Comment: I tried your code this what i want.  From the bottom to top 30% is scroll to top and after again i click it goes to top as 100%. I want it to be 30% itself. For example if i mention 20% percent means five times click to reach top. Hope you got my point  Is there is a way to show the output as with

Comment: You can use a variable which will contain your mentioned percentages i.e. 20% or 30% or anything you want. Inside the function you can add or subtract this variable accordingly.

Comment: Thanks from your fiddle itself for the bottom to top is works only once then again if i click it goes to top not the corresponding percentage did you notice that ?

Comment: Replace this line " var scrollAmount = height * (1 - percentage); " in top function with this "var scrollAmount = height*percentage" .

Comment: Thanks i tried this how it work. . . Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TkYpY/37/ But if i giving 20% percent and tried is not working properly